# Intel CPU OpenCL in Mono killed by SIGXCPU (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, mono, opencl, signal-handling

Some time ago I wrote simple boids simulation using OpenCL (was school assignment), using C#, Cloo for OpenCL and OpenTK for OpenGL output. I tested it on Windows7 with AMD CPU implementation of OpenCL and on friend's NVidia.
Now I tried it on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04). I installed amd app sdk and intel sdk. It compiled ok, reference CPU implementation is working fine with graphic output. But when I try to run OpenCL version, it runs for about 1 second (showing what seems like valid output in OpenGL) and then gets killed by SIGXCPU. Tried to google some known issue, but found nothing.
So I tried to catch and ignore that signal, but everytime I try, program hangs. When I set mono to catch some different signal (e.g. SIGPIPE), it runs ok (minus that kill when opencl).
In Mono, i Tried Mono.UnixSignal as stated in FAQ
Tried

```
Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.SetSignalAction ( Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGXCPU, Mono.Unix.Native.SignalAction.Ignore);
```

then something which doesn't hang, but doesn't help either:

```
Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.SetSignalAction ( Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGXCPU, Mono.Unix.Native.SignalAction.Error);
```

and even

```
ignore (0);
Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.signal(Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGXCPU, new Mono.Unix.Native.SignalHandler (ignore));
```

with

```
static void ignore(int signal) {
}
```

even when I remove everything else from main, it still hangs sometime after "touching" that signal.

One more weird thing:

```
Mono.Unix.Native.Stdlib.SetSignalAction ( Mono.Unix.Native.Signum.SIGXCPU, Mono.Unix.Native.SignalAction.Default);
```

Kills application with SIGXCPU somewhere after Application.EnableVisualStyles(); when I set it right before, not even touching OpenCL this time.

Is there something I missed in Mono? Is it using this signal somewhere internally that it gets in the way of OpenCl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono uses SIGXCPU internally for its own purposes, so if you ignore it (or it's raised for some other reason), things will break.

Comment: that's what I was afraid of. Then I shall try some simpler OpenCL to see, if it gets killed too..

Answer (score 1):

SIGXCPU means that you've exceeded a per-process time limit. Once you've exceeded it, you've exceeded it. The process is stuck. You need to use ulimit, or get help from an admin, to set a higher limit.

Comment: I've seen this with Cuda applications. It seems that sometimes there's a maximum amount of time a Cuda kernel can run on the video card.  If you exceed this time limit the application is killed.

Comment: @bmargulies when I try "ulimit -a" I get "cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited" Is there some Mono-specific setting for this?